# php mail function in Joomla 3.0 not working

Tags: php, email, passwords

I am trying to use the PHP mail function to allow an email to be sent to a user containing their password once they have entered their email address. I realise the security isn't great as I am passing the password via email but I can focus on that later. For now, I just need the functionality. It seems like the code is working as I get my success message returned, but I receive no email, any ideas? 
I am using Joomla 3.0 which is hosted on an Apache Server as part of the XAMPP server solution package. I also changed the settings in the global configuration to SMTP as i saw this on other forums but no luck :( I was wondering would the 'localhost' factor be causing a problem?

My code for the form action (after the user has entered their email) is;

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
  {

   mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die("Could not connect to database");
   mysql_select_db('joomla_lifestyle') or die("Could not select database");

   $email = $_POST['email'];

   $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Email ='$email'");
   $result = mysql_num_rows($sql);

   if ($result == 1)
   {
       $rows = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
       $password = $rows['Password'];
       $email = $rows['Email'];
    $subject = "Password Request";
    $header = "from: ciaraodonovan000@gmail.com";
    $body = "Your Password is " . $password;

    mail($email, $subject, $header, $body);
    $msg = "An Email Containing the Password has been Sent to you!";
    header("Location:/Joomla-Lifestyle/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=9&msg=$msg");
} else
{
   $msg = "User doesn't exist, please try again.";
   header("Location:/Joomla-Lifestyle/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=9&msg=$msg");    
}

    }   
    ?>
```

Comment: Curious, there a reason your not using the built in new user email feature to send the user password after they sign up?

Comment: Yeah, I realise that feature is available but I am being graded based on my code so the work has to be original.

Answer (score 2):

I think your combining two separate concepts required for this to work.  The first being a server to send the email and its configuration and the second being the Joomla back-end settings to utilize the server to send the email.

Using PHP Mail won't work unless the server running PHP (XAMP in this case) has a valid means to achieve SMTP transport.  I always configure Joomla to use SMTP authentication to reach out to the clients mail server and send emails.

For your local development environment, use or set up a Gmail account and use the following settings to be able to send emails within the Joomla framework.

mailer: SMTP

From email: *enter what you like*

From Name: *enter what you like*

Sendmail Path: *leave blank*

SMTP Authentication: Yes

SMTP Security: TLS

SMTP Port: 587

SMTP Username: *your gmail email address*

SMTP Password: *your gmail email password*

SMTP Host: smtp.gmail.com